# Video's audio continues to play after replete modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video-streaming, html5-video

Tried to find a solution for this, but couldn't find anything that worked. I tried

```
$('video').trigger('pause');
```

and there is no close button in the html to attach any script to. However, I do not know jquery or javascript so I am hoping someone can help.

Using 'Replete Modal' which seems to be quite popular but I am having an issue with the video's audio track carries on playing if the modal is closed before watching in full. Seems only to be an issue when viewed on desktop browsers.

Was hoping to find a solution that stops the audio as well.

The below is the HTML code I have inserted:

```html
<div style="margin:50 auto; width:700px;">
  <a class="vimeo" >vimeo</a>
  <script>
   $(window).load( function(){
    rplm({
     title: "ETSA Teacher Training",
     text: '<video width="100%" height="338" controls autoplay><source src="Endeavour Teaching.mp4" type="video/mp4"><!--source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"-->Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>',
     html: true,
     showConfirmButton: true,
     delay: 2,
     animation: 'fadeIn',
     allowOutsideClick: true,
     overlay: "black",
     videoHeight: "338",
     videoWidth: "100%",
  preventDialog: true,
  cookieName: "blockModal",
  preventText: "Block This Pop-up.",
  preventDays: 30,
  modalNOverlay: 'black',
    });
   });
  </script>
 </div>
```

You can see this in action here: http://www.endeavourtsa.org/index-test3.html
Obviously there are css and js files, but as I do no know what portion is needed I did not want to post all of the code here unless I had to.
I can post if requested or you can find the files here:
http://www.endeavourtsa.org/modal.zip

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: when you click the "ok" button to dismiss the rplm pop-up, it's not actually pausing the video, it's simply hiding the pop-up. You'll want to pause the video when the button is clicked

Comment: I know, but I can't work out how to do this. As I mentioned there isn't a button in the html code to attach a script to pause the video. I tried just adding the script but it didn't work and I don't know enough about jquery/javascript to attempt to edit the js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having a look at the source, you'll need to add a video id to the video in the pop-up so you can reference it later (`id="evideo"`)

```
rplm({
    title: "ETSA Teacher Training",
    text: '<video id="evideo" width="100%" height="338" controls autoplay><source src="Endeavour Teaching.mp4" type="video/mp4"><!--source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"-->Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>',
```

and then add an onclick handler to the button that closes the pop-up (unless `rplm` has an eventing model that allows you to more easily attach code to the `close` event for the popup):

```
        modalNOverlay: 'black',
        });
        document.getElementsByClassName("confirm")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){alert('boo')})
    });
</script>
```

(may need some tweaking and additional events as the modal can also be dismissed by clicking outside the box, but would need to see the `rplm` documentation to see if there's a more elegant solution)

Comment: Thanks @Offbeatmammal for your help so far. The fact that all the events seem to be controlled by the .js document has totally thrown me. I tried the above but I think the 'tweaks' need to be made to the js file. The JS files can be found here- (http://www.endeavourtsa.org/modal/js/replete-modal.js),
JS min- (http://www.endeavourtsa.org/modal/js/replete-modal.min.js) or I attached a zip file with the documents to the original post. From what I can see there are 3 sections that deal with the close button/event. Line 46-23, 345-738 and 1523-1552. If you can help further that would be great

Comment: do you have any documentation for the replete-modal code (from what I can see you need to buy a licence to get the docs) - it appears there is a capability to attach a callback function that is fired when then modal is closed so that would be the best way (in the tweak above, did you see the 'boo' alert, or did it never trigger?)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal- thanks so much for your help. I actually decided to try and revert to getting the embed working correctly as I was having issues with the video showing properly across all browsers. But this solution was pretty much there. Thanks for you expertise.