# Stop audio when closing modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, video-streaming

I have a modal that pops up on page load and streams a youtube file. However, when the modal is closed the audio track still continues.
Is there a way to stop audio when the modal closes?

The page in question can be seen here: [Modal audio issue webExample](http://www.robertfitzroyacademy.com/index.html)

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="clear"></div> 
<div style="margin:50 auto; width:800px;">
    <script>
        $(window).load( function(){
            rplm({
                title: "",
                html: true,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                animation: 'fadeIn',
                allowOutsideClick: true,
                modalNOverlay: 'black',
                youtubeID: "FJDkIKPtHUg?autoplay=1&mute=1",
                videoWidth: "780px",
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Hanniel.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for that Replete Modal?

Comment: I do, there is some documentation, the bit on YouTube is very basic though. http://www.robertfitzroyacademy.com/resources/rplm/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Issue looks like the `.close()` call hides the modal and doesn't kill the video or remove the iframe source, similar issue to [Video's audio continues to play after replete modal is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463146/videos-audio-continues-to-play-after-replete-modal-is-closed) theirs being Vimeo.

You could invoke the video with

```
function openModal() {
  rplm({
    title: "",
    html: true,
    text:'<iframe id="rplm-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
  });  
}
```

Using `rplm-player` as the id you can call the following function to close the modal and kill the iframe.

```
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("rplm-player").src = "";
  rplm.close()
}
```